# Can a set of initial values be hinted to MPModelProto?

Tags: java, or-tools

I am working with MPModelProto + GLOP. We have implemented an heuristic that continuously runs the linear model while changing some constraints, so by setting a hint for the linear optimizer at each run with the actual solution from the last run would in thesis improve performance.

I wonder if the following implementation in Java makes sense : it runs fine but I cannot see a sensible difference in performance.

The code basically takes the variable values from the previous solution response and plugs it into a **PartialVariableAssignment**, which is then assigned as the **MPModelProto.Builder** solution hint.

```
        PartialVariableAssignment partialVariableAssignment = PartialVariableAssignment.newBuilder()
                .addAllVarIndex(IntStream
                        .range(0, mpSolutionResponse.getVariableValueCount() - 1)
                        .boxed()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .addAllVarValue(mpSolutionResponse.getVariableValueList())
                .build();      

        model.setSolutionHint(partialVariableAssignment);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint for a LP solver is not a set of values, but the basis. Computing the basis from a set of values is not trivial. So the answer is no.